# Avoiding container.Resolve in simple factory?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

New to Unity & DI. I was passing the container into my view model & calling .Resolve when I wanted a new view instance which I now know is bad practice.

I'm now resolving the view via a simple factory class which is passed into the view Model constructor as an Interface:

```
this.dialogView = this.dialogViewFactory.CreateDialogView();
```

I'm invoking RegisterType in Unity which resolves the view & viewModel:

```
this.unityContainer.RegisterType(typeof(IDialogView), typeof(DialogView));
this.unityContainer.RegisterType(typeof(IDialogViewModel), typeof(DialogViewModel));
this.unityContainer.RegisterType(typeof (IDialogViewFactory), typeof (DialogViewFactory));
```

Finally, my factory class. I am currently passing in the container & calling resolve here. I'm aware that although I've moved the dependency out of the view model I still have the container dependency in the factory class:

```
public class DialogFactory : IDialogFactory
{
    private IUnityContainer unityContainer;

    public DialogFactory(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        this.unityContainer = unityContainer;
    }

    public IDialogView CreateDialogView()
    {
        return this.unityContainer.Resolve<IDialogView>();
    }
}
```

What is the best solution to this?

Comment: See http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory and http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/12/24/placement-of-abstract-factories

Answer (score 0):

You could use Unity's [Automatic Factories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec32) to eliminate the need for the factory by injecting a `Func<IDialogView>`:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private Func<IDialogView> dialogViewFactory;

    public ViewModel(Func<IDialogView> dialogViewFactory)
    {
        this.dialogViewFactory = dialogViewFactory;
    }

    private IDialogView CreateDialogView()
    {
        return this.dialogViewFactory();
    }
}
```

You could also use this approach to inject into the `DialogFactory` itself if you want/need a formal factory:

```
public class DialogFactory : IDialogFactory
{
    private Func<IDialogView> dialogViewFactory;

    public DialogFactory(Func<IDialogView> dialogViewFactory)
    {
        this.dialogViewFactory = dialogViewFactory;
    }

    public IDialogView CreateDialogView()
    {
        return this.dialogViewFactory();
    }
}
```